# Are Objects the Same in Objective-C as They are in PHP?

Tags: php, objective-c, oop, object

I am about to start learning Objective-C and I was wondering whether or not the concepts are the same as with PHP. For example, are the concepts in Object Oriented PHP the same as Objective-C, such as "Class, Instance, Message, Method, Instance Variable, Inheritance, Superclass/Subclass, and Protocol"? If so, this will I am guessing it will be much easier for me to learn and grasp since I already know the basics and foundations of Object Oriented PHP. Or are they completely different from each other?

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All "propper" OO language constructs should be essentially the same. They should always have all of, or a sub section of the the following (and probably more).

- class / object (completely different)
- method (vs function)
- method visibility/access control (public, private, protected)
- constructor
- static/class variables & methods
- destructor/finalizer
- inheritance (and often, multiple inheritance)
- interface/protocol
- abstract class
- overriding
- overloading

there are plenty more terms to do with things that are more conceptual rather than language features, but that's a short (and reasonably incomplete) list of some things that you should know for programming in ANY OO language worth it's salt.

There's a nice little list of terms on Wikipedia to help if you'd like.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_terms

I'd suggest reading about the terms above, as well as

- Instance variables
- Polymorphism
- Composition
- Encapsulation

If you know your defenitions of OO, moving from one language to the next is far simpler, because you will have a very wide base to stand on and only have to learn subtle differences (as with learning any new language after knowing a few, but more so with OO concepts).

Comment: I don't think that overloading is a property of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Another important thing not in the list that PHP has over oldly OOP languages (Obj-C) are magic methods.

Comment: @mario: To me [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) in PHP just look like predefined methods associated with specific behaviour. The same can be done for Objective-C classes if they adopt specific protocols. For example, `__toString()`'s equivalent in Objective-C is `description`, `__set_state` may be equivalent to `initWithCoder:`, `__set` and `__get` may be equivalent to `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:`.

Comment: @dreamlax: I agree about overloading.  You could argue that it is a form of compile time polymorphism, but it's not really in the spirit of real polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

They are basically the same idea, but not implementation, since most of those are CS theory concepts. Messages and protocols don't exist in PHP. PHP has what most languages call an interface which is akin to a protocol in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "Yes."  The medium-length answer has been written by Apple, and you can read it here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html